# How to never rebuild an already built target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using a Makefile to automate the installation of some tools, some of which I download

```
all:bin/symfony

bin/symfony: var/bin/symfonyInstaller
    @echo making $@
    @$< --install-dir bin > /dev/null 2>&1

var/bin/symfonyInstaller: var/bin
    @echo making $@
    @wget -q https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O $@ >/dev/null 2>&1
    @chmod a+x $@ > /dev/null

var/bin:
    @echo making $@
    @mkdir -p $@ > /dev/null

clean:
    @echo making $@
    @rm -rf bin var
```

For some reasons, var/bin/symfonyInstaller is always being remade :

```sh
$ make
making  var/bin
making  var/bin/symfonyInstaller
making  bin/symfony
$ make
making  var/bin/symfonyInstaller
$
```

Is there a way to tell make "don't rebuild var/bin/symfonyInstaller" ?

Comment: Your Makefile uses `installer` but your question mentions `bin/installer`. Is it an error in your Makefile or a typo in your question?

Comment: I am going to edit my question to give the real one then :)

Comment: Ah, I will then edit my question because your problem was actually a directory used as prerequisite.

Comment: Moral of the story: if it is simple enough always show your real Makefile, the real command you type and the real output you get, plus why it is not what you want. Each character matters. Else, create a simpler MCVE but test it ;-).

Comment: thanks for the nice detail on $< as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `var/bin/symfonyInstaller` target is always rebuilt because it depends on the directory in which it goes. And each time it is built the directory's last modification time is updated and becomes newer than the target. Thus the endless cycle.

What you want is called an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types). Every prerequisite mentioned in a make rule before the `|` separator is a "*normal*" one. After the `|` separator it is an order-only prerequisite.

All prerequisites, normal or order-only, are updated before the target, if they don't exist or if they are outdated. The difference is in how make decides to rebuild or not the corresponding target. Make rebuilds the target if it updated a normal prerequisite, or if the normal prerequisite is newer than the target. But not if it is an order-only prerequisite that has been updated or is newer than the target.

In your case you should use it for `var/bin`:

```
var/bin/symfonyInstaller: | var/bin
    @echo making $@
    @wget -q https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O $@ >/dev/null 2>&1
    @chmod a+x $@ > /dev/null
```

If `var/bin` does not exist it is created before `var/bin/symfonyInstaller`, which is good, but `var/bin/symfonyInstaller` will not be rebuilt just because it is older than `var/bin`.